# VS11 Code Analysis Hints?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, static-code-analysis

I got a lot of false positives when running the code analysis for C++ in VS11. For example i have a few dozen switch and it says my pointer may be null. All the cases in the switch (at least in one case) the pointer is set and the default calls my function which throws an assert(0) and exception. I guess since the assert and exception is in a method it doesn't realize its impossible for the pointer to be null. How do i hint or fix it so a false positive like this doesn't show up?

Answer (score 2):

try using [`_Analysis_assume_(FALSE)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b3fsfxw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in the switch, it hints unreachable code to the compiler.

You can also decorate functions that throw and don't return with [`_Analysis_noreturn_`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6ktzx3s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If the method invoked by the default case doesn't return anything, you can try making it return a "fake" null value that will be assigned to the pointer in the default case.

```
Type* MyClass::methodCalledInDefaultCase()
{
    pointer = 0;
    assert(0);
    throw Exception;
    return 0; // Hope this doesn't cause unreachable code warning
}

void MyClass::myMethod()
{
    pointer = 0;
    switch(whatever)
    {
        case foo:
            ...

        case bar:
            ....

        default:
            pointer = methodCalledInDefaultCase();
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ah ha. Ok, i believe this will work but i might as well make a fakeptr() template which returns a pointer to fool it (similar to the fake but occasionally useful auto_cast)